# Treeset comperator remove object

Tags: java, treeset

I have n number of rules in my system. While submitting a request I have to select exact one or with rule as None.

So I have added weight age to each rule, but the problem is if there is no match for the request (one attribute), no need to consider that rule. (I have given maximum score for that rule.) How can I remove that from my `TreeSet`?

Currently this is my compare method:

```
private Flow selectExact(final FlowSelector flowSelector) {
    TreeSet<Flow> sortedFlows = new TreeSet<Flow>(new Comparator<Flow>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Flow o1, Flow o2)
        {
            return o1.calculateWt(flowSelector) - o2.calculateWt(flowSelector);
        }
    }
);
```

`calculateWt` method weight age for each property. I want to sort `TreeSet` based on this `calculateWt` method, but it should not include entries, i.e. `calculateWt > 100`. Sorted `TreeSet` with `calculateWt` is not greater than 100.

Comment: Your code doesn't show any `TreeSet`, but that doesn't really matter, because `compare` is a *read-only* method, it should **never** make any state changes.

Comment: Please see my below comments

Comment: That code doesn't *do* anything. You create a `TreeSet` called `sortedFlows`, and then ... *nothing*. Start over: What are your inputs? What is your output? Input: List of rules, and value to lookup. Output: Best matching rule. --- Is this correct? If so, where are your rules?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I haven't understand the question properly, but usually we need comparator to sort values in tree. If you want to delete some entry in tree - delete it manually, in outer code.

```
Set myTree = new TreeSet(); 
// add some values here
// then compare new, second rule weight with others,
// maybe you need to do it in a loop 
if (compare(first, second) > 100) {
    myTree.remove(second);
}
```

Something like this.

Comment: private Flow selectExact(final FlowSelector flowSelector) { TreeSet<Flow> sortedFlows = new TreeSet<Flow>(new Comparator<Flow>() { @Override public int compare(Flow o1, Flow o2) { return o1.calculateWt(flowSelector) - o2.calculateWt(flowSelector); } }); This is my treeset comperator .I want to sort tree based on the weight age of each attribute(that is calculateWt do).For that sorting purpose ,dont want to include calculateWt >100 entry .remove this entry and want to sort.I cant do it in outer code.Hope you got it

Comment: @user3319065 We don't "got it", because we can't read that. Edit your question to include the code, so it can be formatted in a human-readable way, and so others can easily see *what* the question is.

Comment: @Andreas Any suggestion for this